# Python Textract and Tesseract OCR Lambda Layer

Tags: python, docker, tesseract, aws-lambda-layers

Trying to use [Python Textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python_package.html) and Tesseract-OCR in a Lambda Layer. I am building the .zip for the layer using Docker and Serverless Framework.

**The Issue**:
`textract` works fine as long as the `method` is not `tesseract`, I can process .txt easily. The error I receive when I run the lambda with `textract.process(path, method='tesseract', language="ara")` is:

```
The command `tesseract /tmp/tmp4liccjbq/quran.jpeg stdout -l ara` failed because the executable\n`tesseract` is not installed on your system. Please make\nsure the appropriate dependencies are installed before using\ntextract:\n\n    http://textract.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html\n
```

This all works locally as well. If I build the image and run the container I can `tesseract --help` from the command line in the container easily

If I do a `print(os.listdir(path='/opt/bin'))` from the layer's handler I can see the `tesseract` binary is located at `/opt/bin`

**I think the issue is** how `textract` calls `tesseract`, it is using `subprocess.Popen()` and I wonder if the subprocess does not know the path to the tesseract binary?

If I cannot figure this out I will try to use `pytesseract` since I am aware you can provide a path to the tesseract binary

**Dockerfile**:

```
ARG LEPTONICA_VERSION="1.80.0"
ARG TESSERACT_VERSION="4.1.1"
ARG AUTOCONF_ARCHIVE_VERSION="2017.09.28"
ARG TMP_BUILD="/tmp"
ARG DIST="/build-dist"
# change TESSERACT_DATA_SUFFIX to use different datafiles (options: "_best", "_fast" and "")
ARG TESSERACT_DATA_SUFFIX=_fast
ARG TESSERACT_DATA_VERSION=4.0.0

FROM python:3.9

ARG LEPTONICA_VERSION
ARG TESSERACT_VERSION
ARG DIST
ARG TMP_BUILD

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    pkg-config wget \
    # C/C++ compiler
    clang \
    # GNU Autotools
    autoconf automake libtool \
    # image tools
    libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev \
    # dep for textract
    libxml2-dev libxslt-dev antiword \
    # deps for pdf2image
    poppler-utils build-essential libpoppler-cpp-dev \
    # tesseract v4.1.3
    tesseract-ocr libtesseract-dev \
    # tesseract languages
    tesseract-ocr-ara \
    # needed for training data
    libicu-dev libpango1.0-dev libcairo2-dev \
    # leptonica v1.82
    libleptonica-dev \
    # lambda build deps
    g++ make cmake unzip libcurl4-openssl-dev

# build autoconf
WORKDIR ${TMP_BUILD}/autoconf-build
RUN wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf-archive/autoconf-archive-2019.01.06.tar.xz
RUN tar -xvf autoconf-archive-2019.01.06.tar.xz
RUN cd autoconf-archive-2019.01.06 && ./configure && make && make install
RUN cd autoconf-archive-2019.01.06 && cp m4/* /usr/share/aclocal/

# copy everything we need into the DIST folder to be extracted later
WORKDIR /
RUN mkdir -p ${DIST}/lib && mkdir -p ${DIST}/bin && mkdir -p ${DIST}/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages

# Pip install
COPY ./requirements.layer.txt ${DIST}/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ${DIST}/requirements.txt -t ${DIST}/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages

# tesseract and leptonica deps
RUN cp /usr/bin/tesseract ${DIST}/bin && \
    cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.4  ${DIST}/lib/ && \
    cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblept.so.5.0.4 ${DIST}/lib/liblept.so.5 && \
    cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 ${DIST}/lib/ && \
    cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6.0.2 ${DIST}/lib/ && \
    cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 ${DIST}/lib/ && \
    cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 ${DIST}/lib/ && \
    cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 ${DIST}/lib/ && \
    cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 ${DIST}/lib/ && \
    echo -e "LEPTONICA_VERSION=${LEPTONICA_VERSION}\nTESSERACT_VERSION=${TESSERACT_VERSION}\nTESSERACT_DATA_FILES=tessdata${TESSERACT_DATA_SUFFIX}/${TESSERACT_DATA_VERSION}\nTESSERACT_DATA_LANGUAGES=osd,eng,${OCR_LANG}" > ${DIST}/TESSERACT-README.md && \
    find ${DIST}/lib -name '*.so*' | xargs strip -s
# textract deps
RUN cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.10 ${DIST}/lib/ && \
    cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1.1.34 ${DIST}/lib/ && \
    cp /usr/bin/antiword ${DIST}/bin/
# pdf2image deps
RUN cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.102.0.0 ${DIST}/lib/

RUN chmod 755 ${DIST}
RUN chmod 755 ${DIST}/bin

ENV PATH="${DIST}:${PATH}"
```

Some notes on the Dockerfile:

1. I'm aware I'm doing nothing with the training data, didnt think I needed it to get it to work
2. The resulting dir structure will be

```
/build-dist
  |
  | bin
      tesseract
  | lib
      all the libs
  | python/lib/python3.9/site-packages
      python packages
```

3. I have tried building both tesseract and Leptonica from source:

```
WORKDIR ${TMP_BUILD}/tesseract-build
RUN wget http://github.com/tesseract- ocr/tesseract/archive/${TESSERACT_VERSION}.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf ${TESSERACT_VERSION}.tar.gz
RUN cd tesseract-${TESSERACT_VERSION} && /
    ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make install && ldconfig
```

**requirements.txt**:

```
textract==1.5.0
pdf2image==1.13.1
python-multipart==0.0.5
Pillow>=9.0.1.0,<9.1.0
awslambdaric
```

Build the image, run the container, copy the contents of the built container to `/layer/build-dist` on my local machine

```
#!/bin/sh
IMAGE_NAME="textract-layer"
CONTAINER_NAME="textract-serverless"
docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME -f Dockerfile.deb.build .
export CONTAINER=$(docker run --name $CONTAINER_NAME -d -it $IMAGE_NAME)
docker cp $CONTAINER:/build-dist layer
```

Zip up `layer/build-dist` and deploy to AWS:

```
serverless deploy --stage dev
```

**Serverless.yml**:

```
layers:
  textract:
    path: layer/build-dist
    name: textract-layer
    description: Layer with Tesseract and Textract
    compatibleRuntimes:
      - python3.9
    retain: false

functions:
  extract:
    handler: app/handler.extract
    events:
      - httpApi: POST /extract
    layers:
      - { Ref: TextractLambdaLayer }
    package:
      include:
        - app/handler.py
    timeout: 5
    environment:
      PATH: $PATH:/opt/bin
      LD_LIBRARY_PATH: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/lib
```

Comment: I don't have the ability to test this but is it possible that the tesseract executable is not in your search path? It looks like you are using linux, is that right? Maybe you just need to add the path to tesseract in your search path? I am thinking something like: ```export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/tesseract```

Comment: I am doing that, yes the docker image is based on a debian image. I am doing `$PATH:/opt/bin` as one of the lambda's environmental variables, and as mentioned above after printing the contents of `/opt/bin` the tesseract binary is clearly there, not sure why `textract` doesnt realize this...

Comment: Try https://github.com/bweigel/aws-lambda-tesseract-layer. Because my lambda needed https://pypi.org/project/tesserocr/, that layer wouldn't work for me (it was designed with pytesseract in mind), but their Dockerfile was a good start and I sorted my lambda all in a customised Dockerfile. I could create a layer I suppose, but only when I find time to test that idea. Let me know if you want to know more. Or if you already found a solution, please post here.

Comment: I ended up getting tesseract-ocr installed on the lambda layer by using a the amazon linux base image, similar to the link you shared. But I still ran into other issues with other packages not working well on centos, so I just opted to run it on EC2 instead of lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my experience in building Python Tesseract OCR Lambda Layer:

1. Go to https://github.com/bweigel/aws-lambda-tesseract-layer and build the layer using the dockerfile. The dockerfile will download training data other than English, you may want to remove them.
2. Then create a `Python` folder inside the `layer` folder created just now. Run `pip install pytesseract [other dependencies] -t layer/python` to install the dependencies to the `layer` folder.
3. Run `(cd layer && zip -r - .) > layer.zip` to create a zip folder for your layer.
4. You can then upload the zip file to your layer.

Note: if you are using `pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr`, you should add `config=" -c tessedit_create_pdf=1"` to the function call, otherwise there will be `FileNotFoundError`.